# The name "Randomize" doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am following the Azure documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage.files.datalake-readme?view=azure-dotnet), and it gets confusing towards the code samples, and currently I see this error with "Randomize" function, which they don't have documented...

> The name “Randomize” doesn't exist in the current context

I am just trying to upload/download (get file location) on the datalake for a use case.

```
string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING");
// Create DataLakeServiceClient
DataLakeServiceClient serviceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(connectionString);

// Get a reference to a filesystem named "sample-filesystem-append" and then create it
DataLakeFileSystemClient filesystem = serviceClient.GetFileSystemClient(Randomize("sample-filesystem-append"));
filesystem.Create();
```

Also, is it correct for me to connect using connection string?
I assumed its a legit parameter since i got no complaints, or do I have to use the `StorageSharedKeyCredential` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Randomize` is in the [`SampleTest` class, which is available on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Common/tests/Shared/SampleTest.cs). The method is very simple though:

```cs
public string Randomize(string prefix = "sample") => $"{prefix}-{Guid.NewGuid()}";
```

... so it's really just creating a random string with the given prefix.

Comment: awesome thanks! and can i use the connectionString instead of storagecredentials?

Comment: @Cataster: I don't know anything about that, I'm afraid.